# Fuzzy the Fuzzball

Tags: calculation-puzzle, word-problem

Fuzzy the fuzzball was very sad.
He had lost his fuzz.
Everyone knew if you lost your Fuzz you could no longer be a fuzzball.
Fuzzy went to this friend Frizzy and shared his dilemma.
"Don't worry, Fuzzy," Frizzy said. "You can buy new fuzz in the FuzzyFuzz store."

Fuzzy went to the FuzzyFuzz store and asked to buy Fuzz.
"How much Fuzz do you need?" the clerk asked.
"Enough to make me fuzzy," Fuzzy said. "I'm a perfect sphere, 2.3456" in diameter."

"We sell three types of Fuzz," said the clerk. "Spartan fuzz is \$2.34 per cm². Standard fuzz is \$3.45  per cm². Super Fuzz is \$4.56 per cm²."

"Ok," said Fuzzy. "I have \$543.21. I will spend up to 67% of my money to buy the best Fuzz I can afford. I sure hope I can afford to become Super Fuzzy!"

How fuzzy is Fuzzy the fuzzball after his purchase?

Comment: Dollar signs are used for math formatting. You have to escape them with a backslash (\\\$ to get a dollar sign).

Comment: ^vote for creatively dressing a linear-programming puzzle that clearly is *not* a homework problem, assuming that Fuzzy's goal is to *completely* refuzz, just as Super-bly as possible

Comment: Is the fuzz sold in units of a particular size, or can we assume that it's infinitely divisible?

Comment: @jpmc26 It seems that they can divide the fuzz into any size, though the price is given per cm2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So Fuzzy's total surface area is

> $17.28$

Then

> we multiply that by $2.54^2$ to get cm. 
> $111.483648$

We now find 67% of 543.21

> 363.9507

Now we divide the money into parts. How many $cm^2$ total for each?

> **Super**: 79.91375 cm$^2$ for \$363.9507
> **Regular**: 105.49
> **Spartan**: 155.53

So,

> since only one of them is obviously greater, we can say he can be completely covered in Spartan Fuzz.

Answer (score 6):

Fuzzy's:
EDIT: Thanks to @bleh

> 2.3456 inches in diameter
>   Which is $\approx 2.9789cm$ in radius
>   For an total surface area of $4 \pi 2.9789^2 \approx 111.51cm^2$
>   He has $67\%$ of $\$543.21$ to spend so can afford $\frac{67}{100} *\frac{\$543.21}{111.51cm^2}\approx \$3.26/cm^2$
>   Spartan fuzz is $ \$2.34/cm^2$.
>   Standard fuzz is $\$3.45/cm^2 $
>   Super Fuzz costs $ \$4.56/cm^2$
>   So, Can we mix a bit of Spartan with Standard?

Comment: He wants to use only 67%.