# Fuzzy's Fizzy Dilemma

Tags: calculation-puzzle, physics

[Fuzzy the Fuzzball's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28124/fuzzy-the-fuzzball) friends was going to the Fuzzball Festival, and of course he went along. While there, he saw the most curious display.

The booth was displaying brand new types of Fuzz. There was Sparkly Fuzz to attract attention, Smelly Fuzz to keep people away, and Soda Fuzz which looked somewhat like a shaken seltzer bottle.

But the most popular type of Fuzz was a brand new brand, called Fizzy Fuzz. The Fuzz started off as the most wonderfully Fuzzy Fuzz of all. But moment by moment, the Fuzz would fizz off and disappear, at the rate of one Planck length per Jiffy.

Fuzzy was captivated. He dug out his life savings and made the brilliant investment in Fizzy Fuzz. Soon, this 2.3456" inch diameter sphere was covered a Planck length deep in brilliant Fizzy Fuzz.

How long will it be till Fuzzy the Fuzzball is, once again, Fuzz-less?

Comment: Is the sphere covered in Fizzy Fuzz (as stated in the question), or made of Fizzy Fuzz? If covered, then it's the thickness of the covering that we'd need, not the size of the sphere.

Comment: @Phylyp Assume covering is 1 Planck length in depth.

Comment: I'm curious - is this a puzzle, as opposed to a direct math calculation? We're looking at either the volume or surface area of a sphere made of Fizzy Fuzz, and how many Planck lengths there are in it. Apart from the difference due to the sphere being defined in inches and Planck length being defined in SI units, is there anything that brings this into the realm of a puzzle?

Comment: @Phylyp That’s definitely something to think about - what’s the real puzzle here?

Comment: So seeing the clarification you've given for the selected answer (that it was based on the thickness of the covering), I have to point out that your puzzle was itself framed poorly, and that you provided that detail only after I asked it via an earlier comment. When framing puzzles, do take care that the core elements of your puzzle are in place before you add any flavour text. A puzzle that is missing its essential elements but one which has a lot of fluffy (or in this case fuzzy ) flavour text does a disservice to those attempting to solve it (e.g. Riley's first answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will take

> 2.3456 in * 1 Jiffy / 1 Planck length

Which is about

> 3.6862513*10^33 Jiffies.

That's some very durable Fizzy Fuzz right there

EDIT: If the covering is 1 Planck length then it'll take

> Precisely 1 jiffy

until he's fuzzless.

Comment: @LN6595 - it would help if you clarify which of the two answers contained here is the correct one that you were looking for...

Comment: Bingo! Nice job on your second one.