# Fuzzy's Fuzzy Fuss

Tags: wordplay, science

[Fuzzy the Fuzzball](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28124/fuzzy-the-fuzzball) had to admit it. He was broke. [He didn't have a penny](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65498/fuzzys-fizzy-dilemma) left to cover himself in fuzz. He was feeling totally drained. Everything he had ever taken was gone. Fuzzy felt like the very life was being sucked out of him.

He rolled himself into a counselor's office, sat down, and sighed. "I'm no longer fuzzy. But I'm a fuzzball. At least, I *was* a fuzzball. What am I now if I'm no longer fuzzy?"

The counselor thought for a moment, and replied. "Don't worry. I still can see a fuzzball right here. BECAUSE-"

As he pointed, everything turned very dark and perfectly silent. Fuzzy was never able to hear the end of the sentence.

What was the counselor trying to point out?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with... n [Shmmonyy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory)), nf va gur fgevat gurbel pbaprcg. Ubjrire V fgvyy qba'g dhvgr zngpu nyy gur pyhrf.

Comment: Fuzzy needs some more love..... how about a clue?

Comment: Can you give some more information?

Comment: @jonP hat Look at abl’s comment for a clue.

Comment: @hat the tags are the biggest clue

Answer (score 1):

Is it that

> He was so worried about losing all of his fuzz, that he became a *fuss-ball*?

I suppose this

> Sounds somewhat phonetically similar to fuzzball, possibly...

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment from abl on the main post, and Ln6595 hint to look at the tags I think the answer has something to do with

> fuzzball string theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory)

So The counsellor sees

> Blackhole causing everybody to get sucked into it and immediately die

This is because

> a fuzzball is theorized to be the true quantum description of a black hole (from wikipedia)

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: its on the right track.

Comment: Ok but not quite there